# Ambiguous symbol - cannot convert from ado::DataTypeEnum to DataTypeEnum

Tags: c++, visual-studio, ado

Trying to compile a C++ project containing an SQL library and getting these errors:

```
error C2664: 'CNCQuickADO::ConvertADOType' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'ado20::DataTypeEnum' to 'DataTypeEnum'
    Conversion to enumeration type requires an explicit cast
error C2664: 'CNCQuickADO::ConvertADOType' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'ado20::DataTypeEnum' to 'DataTypeEnum'
    Conversion to enumeration type requires an explicit cast
error C2872: 'DataTypeEnum' : ambiguous symbol
    could be 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\dbdaoint.h : DataTypeEnum
    or 'c:\amc\source\amthrottling\release\msado15.tlh : ado20::DataTypeEnum
```

I use the SQL library in several other projects with no issue like this. So I am guessing it must be something to do with where I'm including the library?

Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: Forgot to mention - C:\amc\source\amthrottling is the directory of the project in which I'm working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may be `using namespace ado20` somewhere in the code. To tell the compiler that you want to use global `DataTypeEnum` type (which you probably do since that is what `CNCQuickADO::ConvertADOType()` expects judging from error messages), declare your variable(s) with fully-qualified type `::DataTypeEnum`.

Comment: Yep, I am indeed "using namespace ado20" and yes, that worked. As I say, I have used the library elsewhere without the need to use :: before the variables, but I just changed the library so :: is used and it all works now. If that's how they really should be then that's fine.. cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The **namespace** is very important design in c++.

In `ado20::DataTypeEnum`, `ado20` is the namespace, `DataTypeEnum` is the name in this namespace.

`ado20::DataTypeEnum` and `othernamespace::DataTypeEnum` are different variables which are distinguished from the namespace.

C++ realizes this by modify the variable name. For example, `ado20::DataTypeEnum` can be processed as `_ado20_DataTypeEnum`, while `othernamespace::DataTypeEnum` be `_othernamespace_DataTypeEnum`.

Another example of using the namespace:

```
using namespace ado20; // declare the namespace 
// other code ...
DateTypeEnum yourvariable; // now you can directly use variable in the namespace
```